# How can I change the visibility of a JTextArea/JTextLabel?

Tags: java, swing, visibility

I tried using `.setVisibility(true)` but got a `NullPointerException`. How can I do this more effectively? I want the labels and fields to start invisible then become visible when the user presses a button. I also want to change the size of an object. Ideas?
Heres one of the line of error:

```
public JLabel lblName;




    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
    lblName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblName.setBounds(10, 91, 79, 19);
    panel.add(lblName);
    lblName.setVisible(false);


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lblName.setVisible(true);
    }
```

All of the above are seperate code snippets that worked flawlessly until I added the 3rd snippet.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a NullPointerException... post your code, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: For visibility try `.setVisible(true)`. For size do you mean the JTextArea? if so use `.setSize(Width, Height)`. If this helps you then I suggest that you search Google before asking on stackoverflow next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the code in your question:

You have a field and local `JLabel lblName` 
You are not initializing the field, only the local variable. Hence your exception.

Comment: so.. like public JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:"); ?

Comment: Or you can simply do lblName = new JLabel("Name:"); in your method.

Answer (score 0):

In other words go to this line:

```
JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
```

and make it say

```
lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
```

What was happening was you were initiating a new local variable and never setting the public variable.